# Send a parameter to a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm new in .NET development and need some help.

I need to display stars in function of a rating. This display will appear in most of my pages into the code.

So, I think that the best way to handle this is using a partial view.

After a few researches, I've found something that should enable me to send this parameter to the partial view.

For example, by calling the partial view like that

```
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Search/_SearchPartial.vbhtml", model.contact.rating)
```

But, I don't know how to catch this parameter inside the partial view. Furthermore, the context won't ever be the same. Sometimes, the stars that I'll have to display will be from another rating. Does it change something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the rating to the partial view you can access it via the `Model` object inside the partial view

```
<div>
<p>Current rating: @Model</p>
<div>
```

For the view to know the type of the model it is dealing with you need to specify the type at the top of your partial view:

```
@model MyNamespace.MovieRating

<div>
 <p>Current rating: @Model</p>
<div>
```

All this assumes that the rating object will always be of the same type. If you have different rating objects, then you will either need to parse them into a single type, or create one view for every type of rating object.

Answer (score 1):

The rating value will be the partial view's Model object (as an integer or double), use it like you would in a normal view.

Answer (score 1):

using editor-templates or display-templates more efficient for that situation. For using templates

1. Create that folders:

   Views / Shared / DisplayTemplates
2. Create an view inside DisplayTemplates folder. Call it `Rating.cshtml` and paste that code:

   ```
   @model int

   <div><p>Current rating: @Model</p></div>
   ```
3. Call this template in your view instead of @Html.Partial:

   ```
   @Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.contact.rating, "Rating")
   ```

Comment: @Html.DisplayFor(Model >= Model.Contact.rating, "Rating"), it says that '>=' n'est pas défini pour les types 'MvcApplication4.ContactDeteils' et 'Integer'.
ps : I'm developping in VB.NET

Comment: finally, I'called it like that : @Html.Partial("~/Views/Search/_SearchPartial.vbhtml", model.contact.rating), and haven't had any problem with the use of the model. thx a lot!